# how to convert an object into integer array in postgress?

Tags: json, postgresql

```
resp_data = array_to_json(array( 
        select jsonb_build_object(
                'id', sp_authorities.db_id ,
                'role_id', sp_authorities.role_id ,
                'srvc_type_id', sp_authorities.srvc_type_id,
                'form_data', sp_authorities.form_data ,
                'sp_cust_fields_json',jsonb_agg(sp_orgs_settings.settings_data->'sp_cust_fields_json')
               ) 
          from public.cl_cf_srvc_prvdr_authorities as sp_authorities
          left join public.cl_tx_orgs_settings as sp_orgs_settings
            on sp_authorities.srvc_type_id = any(unnest(array(
                            SELECT json_array_elements_text(json_extract_path(sp_orgs_settings.settings_data,'srvc_type_id'::integer[])))
                        ))
```

srvc_type_id array is not formed instead malformed array literal error is occuring

[enter image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVciF.png)here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t1We.png)

Answer (score 0):

To convert all the rows of a SELECT query into a single array, use the [array_agg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) function.

```sql
SELECT array_agg(sp_authorities.srvc_type_id) ... -- Gives an array of raw integers
SELECT array_agg(json_build_object('id',sp_authorities.srvc_type_id)) ... -- Gives an array of json objects
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg ... -- Gives a json array of either of the above
```